# Group and count distinct occurrences

Tags: mongodb, distinct, aggregation-framework, robo3t

I am trying to derive a query to get a count of distinct values and display the relevant fields. The grouping is done by the `tempId` and the `date` where the `tempId` can occur `one-to-many` times within a single day and within a time frame.

following is my approach,

```
db.getCollection('targetCollection').aggregate(    
{    
   $match:{    
       "user.vendor": 'vendor1',     
       tool: "tool1",     
       date: {    
           "$gte": ISODate("2016-04-01"),    
           "$lt": ISODate("2016-04-04")    
       }    
    }    
},     
{    
   $group:{    
       _id: {     
           tempId: '$tempId',
           month: { $month: "$date" },     
           day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },     
           year: { $year: "$date" }     
       },    
       count: {$sum : 1}    
    }     
},
{    
   $group:{    
       _id: 1,    

       count: {$sum : 1}    
    }     
})
```

This query generates the following output,

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "count" : 107
}
```

Which is correct but, I would like to show them separated by the date and with the particular count for that date. For example something like this,

```
{
    "date" : 2016-04-01
    "count" : 50
},
    {
    "date" : 2016-04-02
    "count" : 30
},
    {
    "date" : 2016-04-03
    "count" : 27
}
```

P.S. I am not sure how to put this question together as I am quite new to this technology. Please let me know if refinements are required in the question.

Following is the sample data of the mongodb collection that I am trying to query,

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "tempId" : "temp1",
    "user" : {
        "_id" : "user1",
        "email" : "user1@email.com",
        "vendor" : "vendor1"
    },
    "tool" : "tool1",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-03-09T08:30:42.403Z")
},...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with the solution myself. What i did was,

- I first grouped by the `tempId` and the `date`
- Then I grouped by the `date`

This printed out the daily **distinct** count of `tempId`, the result I want. The query is as follows,

```
db.getCollection('targetCollection').aggregate(    
{    
   $match:{    
       "user.vendor": 'vendor1',     
       tool: "tool1",     
       date: {    
           "$gte": ISODate("2016-04-01"),    
           "$lt": ISODate("2016-04-13")    
       }    
    }    
},     
{    
   $group:{    
       _id: {     
           tempId: "$tempId",
           month: { $month: "$date" },     
           day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },     
           year: { $year: "$date" }     
       },    
       count: {$sum : 1}    
    }     
},
{    
   $group:{    
       _id: {     
           month:"$_id.month" ,     
           day: "$_id.day" ,     
           year: "$_id.year"     
       },    
       count: {$sum : 1}    
    }     
})
```

Answer (score 0):

group them via *date*

```
db.getCollection('targetCollection').aggregate([
    {
       $match:{    
           "user.vendor": 'vendor1',     
           tool: "tool1",     
           date: {    
               "$gte": ISODate("2016-04-01"),    
               "$lt": ISODate("2016-04-04")    
           }    
        }    
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                date: "$date",
                tempId: "$tempId"
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the `tempId` needs to be considered. The query I am trying to derive is to get the `count` of each **distinct** `tempId` for each day within the given date range. I have updated the question. :)

Comment: Hey thanks, but I think its closer but its the same as I have. The date should be done as I have done it because the timestamp contains seconds so grouping that would anyway give one intance. I need to get the **total count** of the **distinct** `tempId`s for each day.